# How to save complex class instances in between screen rotation?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm building an Android app that connects through Bluetooth to a device. I've built a fairly complex class `BleManager` that deals with all the Bluetooth aspects of the application. I'm facing a problem tho: whenever I rotate the screen of the phone, the class has some trouble maintaining the state. I won't go into too much detail because I would basically need to paste hundreds of lines of code. The gist of it is that I've found no real way to save the state of **not** UI related objects across screen rotations while searching online. The only way I've found is Parcelize, but it's quite a mess to save anything beyond simple objects.

I've solved the problem by saving the instance of `BleManager` to a static `object`. This is not ideal in general: if I have more than one instance of my class, I couldn't save both of them in the same object. Also, my class takes a `Context` instance in the constructor, and Kotlin throws a warning saying that this causes a memory leak. I've solved this by passing a `contextProvider` to my class's constructor function that returns a `Context` instead of the `Context` object itself.

Is there no better way to reliably save the state of a complex object in between screen rotations? It seems to me that it's something quite basic for this to be so convoluted.

Answer (score 1):

Put it in a ViewModel. This at least will preserve it for config changes. But, it will lose the state if your Activity is destroyed for memory savings and then recreated. If you need to preserve the state even under those conditions, then you will have to do something like turning it into a parcel. You may want to look into the Kotlin Parcelize plugin for making this job easier (more automated).

Your `contextProvider` is a hack that doesn't solve the root leak problem. It only tricks the linter into failing to warn you. Pass an Application instead of a Context, and get the Context from the Application. The Application's Context cannot be leaked because it lives for the lifetime of your process. I know you want to get away from using a static reference in an `object`, but this still applies to any solution where your BleManager is going to outlive an Activity.

Comment: You also might want to read this: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes It gets into things you need to handle, and ways you can do it, and warnings about some of them. Saving state between screen rotations is pretty simple with ViewModels, but that isn't always the only thing you need to do. Because Android doesn't use swap memory, it's designed about the idea that your app's state can be destroyed (e.g. when in the background), so you need to be able to store and recreate that state. That can be quite complex! You might need to look into serialisation libraries

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ViewModel` class provided by the Android Architecture Components. ViewModels are specifically designed to store and manage UI-related data in a way that survives configuration changes like screen rotations. You can use a `ViewModel` to hold a reference to your `BleManager` object and access it from your Activity or Fragment as needed.

This way, the `BleManager` instance will be retained across screen rotations as long as the `Activity` or `Fragment` is not destroyed.

Also with `BleManager` you better to use [`Context#getApplicationContext`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getApplicationContext()) **to not cause memory leaks**. This is a singleton and will not cause them after Activity destroying.

**I do not recommend you to use Parcelable to save big objects from recreating after screen rotation, because you can get `TransactionTooLargeException` if your Bundle will be too large.**

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by use of `ViewModel` class provided by the Android Jetpack architecture components. `ViewModel` is a class designed to store and manage UI-related data in a lifecycle-conscious way. It allows data to survive configuration changes such as screen rotation.

Here is an example how you can use `ViewModel`

Create your Model class that you want to save. Let's call it `MyDataClass`.

Create a new class that extends the `ViewModel` class. This will be used to store the instance of `MyDataClass`

```
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel

class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {
    var myDataClassInstance: MyDataClass? = null
}
```

In your Activity create a `ViewModelProvider` and retrieve the instance of `MyViewModel`.

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider

class MyActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var myViewModel: MyViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        myViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(MyViewModel::class.java)

        // Get the instance of MyDataClass from the ViewModel
        var myDataClassInstance = myViewModel.myDataClassInstance

        // If the instance is null, create a new instance
        if (myDataClassInstance == null) {
            myDataClassInstance = MyDataClass()
            myViewModel.myDataClassInstance = myDataClassInstance
        }

        // Use myDataClassInstance in your Activity
    }
}
```